# How can I get an array of processes using GetProcessesByName in C#?

Tags: c#

I think this is a really easy one but I am trying to do a `foreach` loop where it searches for two processes i've defined in an array:

```
    public void getProcess()
    {
        Process[] localByName = Process.GetProcessesByName("lmgrd_x64_n6"), Process.GetProcessesByName("lmgrd");
        lb_instances.Items.Clear();

        foreach (Process proc in localByName)
        {
            try
            {
                lb_instances.Items.Add(proc.MainModule.FileName + " " + proc.Id);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), ex.InnerException.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```

This isn't the correct syntax, can someone advise the best method for this please?

Thanks,
Sam

Comment: So, you already know the names of the 2 and you just want them in an array..?

Comment: there is no loop in your code

Comment: Or perhaps `Process.GetProcessesByName("lmgrd_x64_n6").Union( Process.GetProcessesByName("lmgrd")).ToArray();`?

Comment: @DangerZone Yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each of `Process.GetProcessesByName` call returns an array of processes. So you not only need to put them in resulting array, but also *flatten* those results. That is easy to do with `Enumerable.SelectMany` method:

```
var names = new [] {"lmgrd_x64_n6", "lmgrd" };    
var localByName = names.SelectMany(name => Process.GetProcessesByName(name)).ToArray();
```

Or you can concatenate two result arrays into one array. Again, `Enumerable.Concat` will help you here:

```
var localByName = Process.GetProcessesByName("lmgrd_x64_n6")
             .Concat(Process.GetProcessesByName("lmgrd"))
             .ToArray();
```

Comment: @CodeCaster I reopened question because it was not correct duplicate. This question is not about using array initializer - its about putting two arrays into one

Comment: I see now, you're right. Thanks for adding the explanation.

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy Thanks for this, I tried it but it still didn't work. I've edited my original post.

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy The for loop doesn't run through. in `localByName` I get {System.Diagnostics.Process[0]}

Comment: @SCramphorn that means you don't have such processes running

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy Apologies - you're absolutely correct. I'm such an idiot. 

Thanks all for your help. I know it was simple!!!

Answer (score 0):

`Process.GetProcessesByName` returns an array, with LINQ `SelectMany` you can loop through them.

```
string[] processNames = {"lmgrd_x64_n6", "lmgrd"};

foreach (Process process in processNames.SelectMany(Process.GetProcessesByName))
{
}
```